# Is there a Trusted application endpoint API for Teams?

Tags: skype-for-business, microsoft-teams

In Skype for Business there's a Trusted Application Enpdpoint API that let us interact with/control meetings in S4B. This can for instance be used for joining S4B meetings anonymously or for having an alias presented to a counterpart. We're utilizing parts from "Skype for business Virtual Health Templates".

Is there or will there be something similar available in Microsoft Teams?

Comment: I don't think that's a programming question but rather one for the vendor's product strategy team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

APIs for interacting with Teams calling and meeting functionality are quite different than they were for Skype for Business. We just introduced the ability to interact with the Teams calling and meeting functionality via applications a few weeks ago (first week of October 2018) so this is very new, but you can do it today.

In particular all the APIs are exposed in Microsoft Graph.

Regarding the trusted endpoints specifically, we are using bots to achieve the same goal. Bot Framework bots already have trusted endpoints - we don't call them that, but that's what they are because we generate JWT tokens to authenticate Microsoft to you and your app to Microsoft. In messaging bots, there's a concept of a "messaging endpoint" - for audio/video bots we've added calling and video endpoints.

For more information, see the overview topic [Calls and online meeting bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/calls-and-meetings/calls-meetings-bots-overview) and [Registering a calling bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/calls-and-meetings/registering-calling-bot).

Comment: Thanks! I'll check the documentation out.
/F